# XPath Failing On Matching Attribute Node for Placeholder

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I'm very new to SimpleXML and XPath, and while I have had success with several examples similar to this, this particular one seems to have me stumped.
First, I set a 'placeholder' at a certain node level, with the @$xml_report_abbrev_bb variable.  However, the xpath in this line of code seems to not work.
My 'error trap' keeps returning "XPath query failed."
Thanks for any leads.

The PHP code:

```
<?php
$url = "test_bb.xml";


$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$xml->registerXPathNamespace('a','http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data');//
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('dmd','http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata');

$xml_report_abbrev_bb = $xml->xpath('//Record[@username="john-smith"]');


if($xml_report_abbrev_bb){
    echo $xml_report_abbrev_bb[0]->INTELL->CONTYPE;
    echo $xml_report_abbrev_bb[0]['termId'].'<br>';

} else {
    echo 'XPath query failed';  
}

?>
```

The XML ('test_bb.xml'):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data xmlns="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data" xmlns:dmd="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata" dmd:date="2012-01-03">
    <Record userId="148" username="john-smith" termId="4" dmd:surveyId="12">
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="D" entryKey="Dylan" text="Dylan"/>
        <INTELL id="14" dmd:originalSource="54TEX" dmd:lastModified="2017-04-18T10:54:29" dmd:startDate="2011-01-01" dmd:endDate="2011-12-31">
            <CONTYPE>Sales Tools</CONTYPE>
            <CONTYPEOTHER>Sales History</CONTYPEOTHER>
        </INTELL>
    </Record>
    <Record userId="149" username="mary-smith" termId="4" dmd:surveyId="16">
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="D" entryKey="Dylan" text="Dylan"/>
        <INTELL id="14" dmd:originalSource="54TEX" dmd:lastModified="2012-04-18T10:54:29" dmd:startDate="2011-01-01" dmd:endDate="2011-12-31">
            <CONTYPE>Other Tools</CONTYPE>
            <CONTYPEOTHER>Sales History Part B</CONTYPEOTHER>
        </INTELL>
    </Record>
</Data>
```

Update: I've tried accessing the dmd:surveyId attribute (of the Record node, set above), without success.  I've tried adding the 'dmd:' prefix like this:

```
echo 'surveyId is...<h1>'.$xml_report_abbrev_bb[0]['dmd:surveyId'].'</h1><br>';
```

Is that an 'xpath only' technique, or do I need to set that outside of the brackets?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as you've registered the `http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data` namespace to the `a` prefix for XPath queries, you would need to use

```
$xml->xpath('//a:Record[@username="john-smith"]')
```

Comment: Thanks - I've tried to access the surveyId attribute.  Would the prefix need to be indicated as shown in my update, above?